# How to get VID and PID of a determined USB in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, usb, macos-sierra

I am trying to build a software, in Swift 3, that reads the data of a specific device. I am using some parts of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41279799/2430555) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662693/2430555) source code.

Currently I am able to get name of the device, using the method `func name()` of the first code.

Based on this, the second code will hook the connection and say to me if the device change the status. But this code needs a VID and PID that the first code doesn't provide. It uses a different way to get a value, reading the buffer and searching for values. I don't know how to do this to get other values. I tried to search something on Google but I don't found anything in Swift/Objc. I have found some codes in other languages, but I can't understand how to implement it right now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you look [USB Device Path In Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008280/usb-device-path-in-swift/46319129#46319129) at my answer. 
There's a swift playground that gives you among other things the vid and pid of usb-devices. It is made as a notification thing, but when you start the USBWatcherDelegate, it gives notification for devices already there.