# libimobiledevice ideviceimagemounter iPhone example

Tags: iphone, macos, mount, libimobiledevice, osxfuse

I've scoured and cannot find an example of this.

The question is how to bundle [`libimobiledevice`](https://libimobiledevice.org/) into a macOS app and access iPhone photos.

I found this answer using `osxFuse`'s CLI but I don't want to try to bundle Brew packages in my app and then run commands to try to mount:
https://superuser.com/a/1135668/528533

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to workaround by bundling [`ifuse`](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse) as an executable and calling it when IOKit detected an iPhone attached: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41279799/1762493

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, can you let me know how you bundled ifuse into an executable?