# macOS - Get information from connected iOS device via USB

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm developing a macOS app which needs to detect & get information from connected iOS devices via an USB cable.

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41279799/3673952) how I can get the name of the devices connected via USB, but I'm only able to get a short name of the device (i.e. *iPhone* instead of *John's iPhone*)

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the device's full name, and other information about the device: iOS version, device id, carrier etc.

Can this be achieved using Swift?

Comment: You know `ideviceinfo` from [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice)? I would assume that you have to directly takt to the device via MacOS usbmux and query the information the same way ideviceinfo does.

Comment: @Robert, I did not know about ideviceinfo, thanks! I will check if I can find a way to directly include it into my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Robert's comment, I found out about [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice)'s `ideviceinfo` which does what I needed. I couldn't find a way to directly include it in my app, but I found the [imobiledevice-net](https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net) repo, which has macOS libraries on the [release page](https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net/releases).

These libraries can be used with the help of [Swift's Process](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process) class.